# Getting HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized when hosting application In IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I hosted a web application in IIS. the application Is windows authenticated application. I enabled windows authentication type and disabled all other authentication types. when I try to browse it i get he below error.

> *"HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied. "*

I checked the IIS log below is the Log detail

> 2013-07-16 11:25:19 10.0.40.159 GET / - 80 - 10.0.40.159
>   Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 401 2 5 1793 2013-07-16 11:25:46 10.0.40.159 GET / - 80 - 10.0.40.159
>   Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 401 2 5 311 2013-07-16 11:25:48 10.0.40.159 GET / - 80 - 10.0.40.159
>   Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 401 1 3221225581 2105

I tried to change authentication Type to anonymous type. i did not get the above error that time. i also granted full access to the folder.

PLease help me resolving the error

Comment: if changing to anonymous stopped the error what's the problem?

Comment: All of the questions you've asked on this site have been off topic, please read the [faq]. Your questions are more suited to server fault. SO is about programming not IIS.

Comment: best place to ask this question is here [IIS Forums](http://forums.iis.net/)

Comment: Also refer to this "IIS Binding with windows authentication" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180851/iis-binding-with-windows-authentication#

Answer (score 2):

Try this configuration

```
<deny users = "?" />
<allow users = "*" />
```