# IIS 8 and Windows Authentication

Tags: windows-8, windows-authentication, iis-8

I'm having a bit of a hard time figuring out why windows authentication is a acting up in IIS 8 and how to solve a custom deployment.

After almost a day of brute-force debugging why windows authentication simply wouldn't work on my local machine, it turns out that the host name had to be very specific. The only way to get windows authentication to work is to bind to:

`localhost:80` or `computername:PORT` where `PORT` is some reasonable port.

In my hosts file I mapped `test` to `127.0.0.1` or to `::1` but it simply don't authenticate me. I've tried to keep everything as nearly to a clean install as possible to avoid other variables.

My problem: How do I make windows authentication in IIS8 through a binding such as  `http://test:80`? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it seems this is a *security* feature and it is documented here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896861

Relevant answer here: [IIS Binding with windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180851/iis-binding-with-windows-authentication)

Comment: @Bachask8 What do you mean? The support page is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 8 Basic, it will not show up under "Turn on/off Windows Features" under Control Panel > Programs and Features.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1206923.aspx

Comment: Not sure what you mean, basically what was going on is that IIS was validating the HOST name where the authorization request was coming from. So, even if you have DNS/hosts setup to route the request to your IIS server, windows auth will fail unless you specifically tell windows, the server name is truly the local server. The other option was to disable the check in the registry.

Comment: This question relates to IIS8, not Windows 8.

Comment: I was using Windows 8 to test, so I added the tag, even though the issue (or question) doesn't stem from that OS